# How to deep clone a Map or Set in js?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Suppose we have objects as map values and we want to deep clone the map. What is the proper way to do it?

Answer (score -3):

**Edit:** If the values are not set or map this will work.

Deep clone:

```
var deepClonedMap = new Map(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify([...originalMap])))
var deepClonedSet = new Set(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify([...originalSet])))
```

```js
let originalMap = new Map()
let data = {a:'a',b:'b'}
originalMap.set(1,data)

let shallowCloned = new Map(originalMap)
let deepCloned = new Map(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify([...originalMap])))
data.a = 'p'
console.log('originalMap:',[...originalMap])
console.log('shallowCloned:',[...shallowCloned])
console.log('deepCloned:',[...deepCloned])
```

Comment: Have you tested this with something like `originalMap.set(2,new Set([1,2,3,4]))`?

Comment: Won't this break if the original map or set has circular references (i.e. some entry contains within it a reference back to the original set or map)?

Comment: you are right, this works only if values are not set or map themselves.